# UIButton is not highlighting when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My `UIButton` instance is not highlighting when pressed. I'm pretty sure my code is correct. This only happens in this specific class that I am using. I'm guessing because the function has been overridden by a protocol that I am conforming to.

I want to make the `UIButton` highlight the default way, but I have to do it manually. How can I force highlight the button when pressed, and what are the default settings for it (in terms of colour), so that it is consistent with all the other buttons?

Here is my current code:

```
    let backButton = UIButton()
    backButton.setTitle("back", for: .normal)
    backButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    backButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
    RevealBar.addSubview(backButton)
    backButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.center.equalTo(RevealBar)
        make.width.equalTo(RevealBar)
        make.height.equalTo(RevealBar)
    }

    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Try initializing using `UIButton(type buttonType: UIButtonType.system)`

Comment: @matt I had to settitlecolor because by default, the text colour was white.. but now that i changed the type to .system it works without it

Comment: Moved it to an answer

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Initialize the button using `UIButton(type buttonType: .system)` instead of `UIButton()`.

When you use the latter it won't properly set up button highlighting because the default button type is `UIButtonType.custom`, which is intended as a blank slate without any of the default styling or highlighting behaviour.

Note, from [Apple's `UIButton` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton):

> A button’s type defines its basic appearance and behavior. You specify
>   the type of a button at creation time using the *init(type:) method or
>   in your storyboard file*. **After creating a button, you cannot change
>   its type.** The most commonly used button types are the Custom and
>   System types, but use the other types when appropriate.

Comment: if you share a gist with your code I'll be happy to take a look

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct except this line `let backButton = UIButton()`. Here you need to say button Type. Either you can init with **Frame** or **Button Type**

Comment: If you initialize using the frame initializer the type will still be custom and the button will not have the OP's desired default highlighting.

Comment: And as I note in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41401769/1032372) it is not possible to set the type after the button has been created (whereas it is possible to change the frame anytime).