# Swift text attribute issue: Letter Spacing + Highlighted

Tags: ios, swift, button, swift4

I have a button

> buttonSign

created and tested with the highlighted change of colour.
I need to create also -0.5 letter spacing with:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (buttonSign.titleLabel?.text!)!)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: -0.5, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (buttonSign.titleLabel?.text!.count)!))
buttonSign.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
```

The button code:

```
let buttonSign = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 170, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-41-56-16-56, width: 340, height: 56))
buttonSign.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
buttonSign.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
buttonSign.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 95.0 / 255.0, green: 84.0 / 255.0, blue: 216.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
buttonSign.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signUpAction), for: .touchUpInside)
buttonSign.layer.cornerRadius = buttonSign.bounds.size.height / 2
buttonSign.clipsToBounds = true
buttonSign.setTitle("SIGN UP",for: .normal)
buttonSign.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 20)
buttonSign.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 111.0 / 255.0, green: 107.0 / 255.0, blue: 244.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

view.addSubview(buttonSign)
```

This works but when I apply

> attributedString

It doesn't change the colour of text when highlighted. 
How is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401593/uibutton-is-not-highlighting-when-pressed ? Also, I'd put different `setAttributedTitle(_, for:)`, one for the `.normal` with the white color and one for the `.highlighted` with the blue color.

Comment: For attributed strings shouldn't you be setting the color as an attribute rather than buttonTitleColor and thereby setting another title with the required color for the selected state?

Comment: @Larme, UIButton(type buttonType: .system) ? I had a look at this question and even though have no idea how to make this.
1. UIButton(type buttonType: .system) - I have .custom
2. I've already declared as a UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 170, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-41-56-16-56, width: 340, height: 56))

Comment: You can do :`let buttonSign = UIButton(type: .custom); buttonSigne.frame = CGRect(...)`.

Comment: @Larme, Do you think I didn't try this for both cases?)
1. by "_" you are ignoring the most valuable part of the code "-0.5" letter spacing.
2. It doesn't work.

Comment: I can't guess what you've tried and what you haven't. I don't understand the issue with the letter spacing you are saying. You know you can adds a color and a kern attribute to your attributedString, no? You are mixing `String` & `NAttributedString` properties (you shouldn't do that, it's not recommended in `UILabel`/`UITextView` to mix `.text` & `.attributedText`, and for the button, you are mixing accessing the `label` and using `set(... forState)`.  I'd do this: https://pastebin.com/81gqv27e

Comment: @Larme Thank you so much! I will read about this now :)
I wonder maybe I have to try attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: range) and set the both values here ...